# Routing localhost and only localhost over another network on linux?

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, nat

### Problem description:

I have a rather complicated issue where I can't seem to figure out how to effectively tackle it; Suppose there's the following setup:

There is 1 linux machine, connected to 3 sets of networks, let's call them A, B, and C.

The linux machine can get through the internet through network A. It has a **private** ip address on this network, but **NO** NAT is enabled on it; e.g. any other machines that are routed through this network which have a **public** ip given out by it can connect to the internet through it, but the computer in question cannot do so.

Network B is a **public** ip network set; a set of several public networks. By default,  packets from B are either routed back into B, and for all other destinations not in B are routed via A.

Network C is, like A, also a network where the machine has a **private** address. However, here NAT **is** enabled. Network C can be used to communicate with the internet, but devices on network B are not allowed to route through C, they have to route through A.

Currently, the linux machine can't talk to the internet. I want it to be able to do so (e.g. ping www.stackoverflow.com to not return timeout).

How to tell linux to use another gateway for its own traffic, and only its own traffic (source or destination == localhost)?

### Important

I do not want to route all the traffic to the internet over just one network. The traffic coming/going to the internet needs to use **two** networks, depending on source: Everything from the linux machine over one network (C), everything that it routes (that isn't on one of its local ranges), it routes over the other one (A).

### Tentative solution

First, I thought to just add 'from/to localhost' to the `ip rule` table, yet this is not allowed. What's the easiest way to allow this router to use another router on network C as its gateway, but only from traffic originating from the machine itself?

Essentially, what I'd want is something that would be equivalent to the example below, if that would actually work in the naïve, intuitive way:

```
0: from all lookup local
32000: from localhost lookup myroute
32100: from all lookup main 
32767: from all lookup default
```

Comment: The traffic isn’t originating from localhost because that’s the loopback connection.

Comment: Confusing terminology aside, my intent should be clear; traffic originating from the machine itself: I want it to pick the IP in network C by default as its own IP, but it's trying to go through A (which fails). Traffic coming from B: route through A.

Comment: Whatever the solution is, it doesn't involve rerouting the loopback device. If I understand you correctly, you want to use network C as the default route, and NATing your Linux box on C already works. So use something like `ip route add default dev eth-for-network-C via ...`. If that doesn't work, please edit your question with the output of `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: @dirkt. This is not the correct answer and the only answer I've found online so far. When doing a plain 'route everything via X' that would include the traffic coming via network B, when what I want is; the computer itself uses a gateway in C, but everything which comes from network B sent via the gateway of A. This box is an actual router, not just an endpoint.

Comment: No, traffic coming via network B is only forwarded to network C if you enable forwarding, and normally this is disabled. If you want to use the computer *both* as forwarding router and as normal machine, then yes, policy routing helps (or you can use `iptables`). But you still need the default route to network C, and it still has nothing to do with "forwarding localhost". Localhost is the address of the computer itself via the loopback device ("network D", if you want), and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following configuration with two network namespaces, and two veth pairs:

```
+-- Main --+
|          | 192.168.2.21/24
|    wlan0 | ------------------- ...
|          |
|          | 10.0.0.254/24   10.0.0.1/24 +-- NS0 --+
|   veth0a | --------------------------- | veth0b  |
|          |                             +---------+
|          |
|          | 10.0.1.254/24   10.0.1.1/24 +-- NS1 --+
|   veth1a | --------------------------- | veth1b  |
|          |                             +---------+
+----------+
```

The goal is to route all traffic from `Main` to `wlan0` (network C), while routing everything from `veth0` (network A) through `veth1` (network B).

There's a normal default route on `wlan0`, acquired via DHCP:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 
...
```

Forwarding is enabled:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

We add a default route for `veth1a` in a new table, assuming `10.0.1.1` is the gateway:

```
sudo ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 table 250 dev veth1a src 10.0.1.254
sudo ip route add default table 250 dev veth1a via 10.0.1.1
```

All traffic from and to `veth0a` (10.0.0.0/24) uses this table:

```
sudo ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table 250
sudo ip rule add to 10.0.0.0/24 table 250
```

If somebody behind `veth1b` (10.0.1.0/24) has the stupid idea to try to use us as a gateway, prevent forwarding to `wlan0` and forward right back using the same table. This will usually generate ICMP error packets:

```
sudo ip rule add from 10.0.1.0/24 table 250
sudo ip rule add to 10.0.1.0/24 table 250
```

Adapt to your setup as necessary.

No `localhost` was even remotely mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Try ip ru add from 0.0.0.0

I tested on my router, locally originated connections match the rule, routed connections don't.